# Toggling a background color change by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I was quickly doing a jsFiddle to learn more about the jQuery API, and a fiddle isn't working the way I expected.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5Fc/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
background:red;
height:100px;
width:150px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('div').click(
    function(){
        $(this).toggle(function(){
            $(this).style.background="blue";
        }
        //function(){
        //this.style.background = "orange";
        //}
        );
    }
);
```

Strangely, the div disappears when I click it, and if I uncomment the commented lines the sketch doesn't work at all. Any suggestions or info appreciated.

Comment: Where is your link to the jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5Fc/

Comment: Sometimes, just reading the documentation can help a lot: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. However, note that this method is deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the `toggle()` in the `click()` method, just use:

```
$('div').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/).

Also, you're mixing jQuery and JavaScript:

The jQuery `$(this)` object has no `style` method; that requires the use of the `css()` method; the two approaches are not interchangeable, so you could either use the `css()` approach (above), or stick with plain-JavaScript:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

For example, or switch from jQuery to plain JavaScript:

```
$(this)[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Or:

```
$(this).get(0).style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Both of these approaches essentially retrieve the plain DOM node/object from the jQuery object which allows native JavaScript methods to be used, it does, however, mean that you can't then use jQuery methods on those node(s)/object(s) (unless you re-wrap them in a jQuery object, of course).

Of course, if you just want to use jQuery to handle the event-delegation, you could use the `click()` method, coupled with a ternary:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor == 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: It's because (I *assume*, since there was no comment), in my first draft, I hadn't seen the mix-up of plain JavaScript chained to jQuery; it was deserved at the point it was down-voted (but thanks!) =D

Comment: that was a good answer. Thx. `this.style.background='blue';` also works. Noticed I forgot that comma two between the `function()`s.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of some help! And yes, the native `this` is always available within the jQuery methods, which is why you often see `$(this)` used within the method functions (just to create a jQuery object from the available DOM node).

Answer (score 1):

You just used wrong toggle. There are two `toggle`s:

[toggle Event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

and

[toggle Effect](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

In your code, toggle Effect were executed  which simply show/hide an element. That is why it disappears when you click it.