# Click to change element color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote this little script to change a class color on click, it works, but i would to restore the primary color with a second click.

```js
function changeColor1() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").className = "red";
   
}


function init() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").onclick = changeColor1;

}

window.onload = init();
```

```css
.red {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="ip-custom">Example</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling a background color change by clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033265/toggling-a-background-color-change-by-clicking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle class `red` like following.

```
function changeColor1() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").classList.toggle('red');   
}
```

**Full snippet**

```js
function changeColor1() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").classList.toggle('red');   
}


function init() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").onclick = changeColor1;

}

window.onload = init();
```

```css
.red {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="ip-custom">Example</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use plain js use the `classList.toggle` function:

```
function changeColor1() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").classList.toggle('red');   
}
```

If you use jQuery you can use the `toggleClass` function:

```
function changeColor1() {
    $("#ip-custom").toggleClass("red");
}
```

- [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) documentation
- [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) documentation

Answer (score 1):

Since you have included the tag `jquery`, I'll provide an answer using that and plain old javascript.

**JavaScript**

Check for the existence of the class to determine if you should then add or remove it.

```js
function changeColor1() {
  if (document.getElementById("ip-custom").className == "red")
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").className = "";
  else
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").className = "red";
}


function init() {
  document.getElementById("ip-custom").onclick = changeColor1;
}

window.onload = init();
```

```css
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="ip-custom">Example</button>
```

**jQuery**

You can make use of jQuery's [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ip-custom').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ip-custom">Example</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solutions only works in your case, when element has no class. 
So, it add red class o remove all clasess;

```js
function toggleClassRed() {
    var element = document.getElementById("ip-custom"),
        clazz = element.className || '';

    element.className = clazz === '' ? 'red' : '';
}


function init() {
    document.getElementById("ip-custom").onclick = toggleClassRed;

}

window.onload = init();
```

```css
.red {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="ip-custom">Example</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple solution to save the state in a variable.

```
var clicked = false;

function changeColor1() {
   if(!clicked){
      document.getElementById("ip-custom").className = "red";
      clicked = true;   
   }else{
         document.getElementById("ip-custom").className = "";
         clicked = false; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Why use a boolean variable and not check `document.getElementById("ip-custom").className == "red"` in your condition?